# Magento 2 Home Page / Dashboard is not loading after installation

Tags: magento2, installation, dashboard

[image]

---

I have installed Magento 2, Then I have tried to go to home page of my project but this is not going to the using the URL: http://magentotestapp.magento.com/ but this page is not loading

Comment: Did you check for file permissions chmod -R 777 var/ pub/ generated/

Comment: Can you show me how to check the permissions and how do I configure them I would really appreciate that

Comment: You just need to run this 'chmod -R 777 var/ pub/ generated/ ' command from your magento project directory

Comment: I'm having trouble running this command in cmd in C:\xampp\htdocs\magentoTestApp

chmod is not recognized function

Comment: Try with cmder CLI. Go to your project directory and run permission command.